# Querystring gets shortened in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a page with an url that looks like this: `/urlpart1/urlpart2?firstid=3`.

On that page I have a dropdownlist that will append to the url the value of the chosen item. This is done with jQuery.

```
function categorieClicked()
{
  var categorieId = $("#Dropdownlist").val();
  window.location.href = '/urlpart1/urlpart2?firstid=@Model.FirstId' + '&categoryid=' + categorieId;
}
```

The page redirects, and I have the category value, but the problem is that the url looks like it did before:

```
/urlpart1/urlpart2?firstid=3
```

instead of

```
/urlpart1/urlpart2?firstid=3&categoryid=5
```

Why is this?

Comment: Might be relevant: Can you do a `$.post()` instead of `window.location.href`?

Comment: @AlexR., but this will do an AJAX call and the current url won't change at all which is what the OP is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had two submit buttons on my page.